# How connect a Container View Controller with view

Tags: ios, uiview

I implement Container View Controller inside my view controller and make it class UIView contain several outlet ,When I am trying to connect my label to outlet never connect .

simply I have class :UIView with outlet 
I want to connect outlet inside class with label in view controller

Answer (score 0):

Did you set custom class to your view in storyboard?

[image: Custom class]